# Zoho API access token via php curl give error Invalid client

Tags: php, php-curl, zoho

I want to access zoho APIs, but when I try to get access token then give error invalid client.
My code is as follows:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('client_id' => 'xxxxxxx','client_secret' => 
'xxxxxx','redirect_uri' => 'https://mailedforme.com/','grant_type' => 'access_token'),
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Cookie: JSESSIONID=AFBA9977A8E26493C2CDF129CA3A3689; _zcsr_tmp=f353c6a1-d9bd-4877-abad- 
 4cbb67a6a797; b266a5bf57=a7f15cb1555106de5ac96d088b72e7c8; iamcsr=f353c6a1-d9bd-4877-abad- 
 4cbb67a6a797'
 ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Result is:

> {"error":"invalid_client"}

Comment: maybe you have wrong client id and client secret

Comment: @DarkShade I have correct client id and secret code. but I found also other peoples issue about it. one said that As far as I know, Zoho projects supports only OAuth grant type "authorization_code". The other grant types are not supported.

Comment: So, basically what you are saying is - you are not developing this by following the API documentation yourself, but based on guesswork and hearsay ...? That's an approach you should change then.

Comment: (Not sure why you would send any _cookie_ values to such an API endpoint either. That certainly makes no sense in this context. It's an endpoint that is not supposed to be consumed from the client side to begin with.)